# Simplifying Boolean Function

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am in a computer class with Karnaugh Maps and one of the questions is X 'Y Z + X 'Y 'Z + 'X Y 'Z + X Y Z and I need to simplify it

where ' means not so 'x means not x.

I think the answer is X 'Y + X Z + 'X Y 'Z but I am not sure, if I am wrong can anyone correct me or tell me if this is the correct answer.

Also is it possible to turn a Boolean function into a Karnaugh Map?

X 'Y Z + X 'Y 'Z + 'X Y 'Z + X Y Z to a Karnaugh Map, I am wondering because that is what i did to get that answer above, but I am not sure if it is allowed.

edit: can a kmap like this be used to solve it?

xyz  00 01 11 10

0              1
1     1  1  1

Comment: Try this neat website, which is able to transform Boolen formulas into DNF and CNF: http://www.izyt.com/BooleanLogic/applet.php

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your proposed answer:

I'll use the prime $'$ immediately following the variable, so that $X' = \text{not}\; X$. I use the distributive law twice: $ab + ac = a(b+c)$, and then I use the identity that $a + a' = 1$:

$$\begin{align} X Y' Z + X Y' Z' + X' Y Z' + X Y Z & = XY'(\underbrace{Z + Z'}_{\large =1}) + Y(X'Z' + XZ) \\ \\ & = XY' + Y(X'Z' + XZ)\end{align}$$

Or, equivalently $XY' + X'YZ' + XYZ$

Comment: so is it not possible to use a kmap?

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU! +1

Comment: Your solution is the same as his.  $XY'Z$ is included in $XY'$ so $XY'+XYZ=XY'+XZ$